# Парсинг страниц

Tags: php

Есть страничка вот эта http://demonscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1186550345

Нужно получить данные вот этой функции

```
<script type="text/javascript">DrawOnline(1357823766,1358033900)</script>
```

Как можно это сделать? не используя регулярные выражения!

Answer (score 4):

А в чём проблема? Грубое решение -- ищете (без регулярных выражений, просто поиском строки) текст "DrawOnline" на странице, от него вперёд открывающую скобку, от неё вперёд закрывающую. То, что между скобками -- искомое.

Если хотите более концептуальное решение, попробуйте настоящий парсер. Например, такое (не пробовал, основываюсь на документации):

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTMLFile($url);
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('script') as $scriptnode) {
    $script = $scriptnode->nodeValue;
    if (strpos($script, "DrawOnline") === false)
        continue;
    // анализируйте текст скрипта
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял под Вашим "данные".

```
function DrawOnline(last_enter, now){
if(now==='online'){
    doc.write('Персонаж сейчас находится в клубе.')
} else {
    doc.write('Персонаж не в клубе')
    if(last_enter!=='hide'){
        doc.write(
            ', но был тут:<br/>'+
            CombatsUI.UTCMsec2PlainText(CombatsUI.UTCMsec2Moscow(last_enter*1000))+'<img src="http://img.combats.ru/i/clok3_2.png" title="Время сервера" /><br/>'+
            '('+LocalText.PeriodToText('ru', now-last_enter, 2, 'ACC')+' назад)'
        )
    }
}
```

}

Получает время в Unix-формате предположительно.

**UPD:**

[[@quaresma89](/users/7018/quaresma89)](/users/7018/quaresma89), Вы посчитаете меня занудой, но я все равно Вас не понял)) Вам нужен результат выполнения этой функции или объяснение зачем нужны параметры этой функции?
Просто "их(параметры) мне и надо вытащить" - их незачем вытаскивать) Они уже тут))

Параметры: last_enter - время последнего посещения, now - текущее время. Хранятся в UNIX-формате, т.е. число секунд с 1 января 1980 года. Они генерируются (подставляются) на сервере вероятно. Если совпадают, то онлайн, иначе высчитывается разница между последним посещением и текущим временем (чтоб вывести как давно не заходил) и переводятся в "человеко-читаемый" формат. Если не то, то опишите подробней что Вам нужно)

**UPD2**

Не сразу заметил. now почему-то сравнивается со строкой "online", хотя передается число. Там наверно онлайн никого не бывает))

Comment: Ну немного не так выразился извиняюсь.Параметры функции интересуют DrawOnline(1357823766,1358033900) вот их мне и надо вытащить.

Comment: Мне нужно написать небольшой монитор персонажа,то есть отслеживать его онлайн,когда персонаж онлайн параметры функции вот такие  DrawOnline(1357823766,'online'),поэтому мне и надо их вытащить!

Comment: @quaresma89, я просто cUrl-ом посылал запрос, в страничке искал текст "Персонаж сейчас находится в клубе.", если есть - онлайн, нет - неонлайн)

Comment: Не все так просто)) Есть персонажы которые даже при онлайне не высвечивается надпись "Персонаж в клубе" а только локация где он находится.Поэтому и нужно мониторить по параметру онлайн!

Answer (score 0):

[simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) тебе в помощь очень мощная вещь для работы с html